# Unable to call web service function even though it works fine in the test form

Tags: php, soap

I am making a php/c# console app/c# soap service and I have created many functions within the web service, but I am unable to call one of them.

The function I am calling is a function which gets a string value from the database. The call works fine on Windows (using localhost) but when putting it onto a Linux server running under mono I get an exception stating the following:

> Function ("getLastResetTime") is not a valid method for this service

The strange this is though, from the Linux server I can access the test form by going to asmx file and run the getLastResetTime function and it returns what is expected, it just seems to be the PHP that can't make the call.

Below is the code that I am using in PHP to call the script

```
function getLastResetTime()
{
    include ("../../config.php");
    include ("../../includes/get-settings.php");
    include ("../../includes/general.php");
    try
    {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://192.168.1.74/EmailServer/EmailSoapService/EmailSoapService.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0));
    $result = $client->__soapCall("getLastResetTime", array());

    echo "Last Reset: " . $result->getLastResetTimeResult;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The screenshot below proves that the web method is working under Mono and what it returns

[image]

Below is the code of the web service function

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Gets the time the Email Server last reset")]
public string getLastResetTime()
{
    SoapHandler soapHandler = new SoapHandler();
    return soapHandler.getLastResetTime();
}
```

and below is the code that the web service calls

```
public string getLastResetTime()
{
    try
    {
        using (ConnectDb db = new ConnectDb(appSettings))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM settings";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.conn))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.GetString("setting") == "app_lastRestart")
                        {
                            return reader.GetString("value");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "N/A";
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this isn't working, I'm guessing I've probably missing something really simple but can't find it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out the reason, but I don't understand why this doesn't affect the methods.

Basically, I was setting the WSDL to be the IP Address of the server (even though it was local to the server) so I was putting `http://192.168.1.74/MySoapService.asmx` but if I change it to `http://localhost/MySoapService.asmx` it works fine.

Why would I need to make it localhost instead of IP address for these services to work.

Is it because I am running several soap requests one after the other so the browser is stopping it, I did notice while I was trying to work out the problem, that Chrome was stating that it was throttling, if this is the issue then I would have thought the connection would time out, not say that the service is invalid.

**UPDATE**
I've now found out why changing the url from the IP to localhost fixed the issue, I realised as another function started having the same problem and later realised that php by default caches the wsdl, if this option is disabled in the php.ini file and restart the apache server, it then works fine. Probably quite useful in a production environment but a bit of a pain when development.